# How does one prevent embeded images from exposing website folder structure via their sources when page is inspected (developer tools)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

I'm developing a PHP web app and I feel concerned that image paths expose their locations (directory path) when the developer tools is opened for page inspection.

Example:
"app/users/secretUsers/johnDoe.img"

Shouldn't this undermine the security of the site in some ways? Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: _"Shouldn't this undermine the security of the site in some ways?"_ - why? What about me knowing that a specific folder exists, appears "threatening" to you?

Comment: I wonder why this question down voted. Let hackers know your server's folder structures could expose application in danger in some manner. I guess this question is quietly reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Most PHP frameworks have a public directory to place the images, Javascript, CSS, etc.

But if you are creating a web app without using a framework, the easiest workaround I used is to create a `index.php` in my public directories and redirect all the requests to the homepage.

Example:
If your url is `www.mywebApp.com/images` then you will be redirected to the homepage. But if your url is `www.mywebApp.com/images/user.jpg` then you can access the image.